# XSLT 1.0 text nodes printing by default

Tags: xslt, pattern-matching

I have looked at [XSL xsl:template match="/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127108/xsl-xsltemplate-match) but the match pattern that triggered my question is not mentioned there.

I have a rather complex XML structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MATERIAL_DATA>
<LOG>
    <USER>Peter</USER>
    <DATE>2011-02-18</DATE>
    <MATERIALS>
        <item>
            <MATNR>636207</MATNR>
            <TEXTS>
                <item>
                    <TEXT>granola bar 40gx24</TEXT>
                </item>
            </TEXTS>
            <PRICES>
                <item>
                    <MATNR>636207</MATNR>
                    <COST>125.78</COST>
                </item>
            </PRICES>
            <SALESPRICES>
                <item>
                    <B01>
                        <MATNR>636207</MATNR>
                        <CURR>CZK</CURR>
                        <DATBI>9999-12-31</DATBI>
                        <DATAB>2010-10-05</DATAB>
                    </B01>
                    <B02>
                        <item>
                            <PRICE>477.60</PRICE>
                            <KUNNR>234567</KUNNR>
                        </item>
                    </B02>
                </item>
            </SALESPRICES>
        </item>
    </MATERIALS>
</LOG>
</MATERIAL_DATA>
```

Now if I apply the following XSLT, my output looks correct:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @*" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="B02">
    <xsl:element name="Mi">
        <xsl:value-of select="item/KUNNR"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Mi>234567</Mi>
```

But if I apply the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="MenuItems">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="LOG/MATERIALS/item/SALESPRICES/item"/>
    </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
 
<xsl:template match="B02">
    <xsl:element name="Mi">
        <xsl:value-of select="item/KUNNR"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MenuItems>
                    
                        636207
                        CZK
                        9999-12-31
                        2010-10-05
<Mi>234567</Mi>
</MenuItems>
```

All values from the element `<B01>` are in the output! But why - I am not matching `<B01>`!?
How does

```
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
<xsl:apply-templates select="* | @*" />
</xsl:template>
```

make the output come out correctly? All I am doing with this is match all nodes or attributes and apply-templates to everything or all attributes.
But in my opinion it should not make a difference to when I exactly match `<B01>`!
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

XSLT includes the following [default templates](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/defaultrule.html) ([among others](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule)):

```
<!-- applies to both element nodes and the root node -->
<xsl:template match="*|/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- copies values of text and attribute nodes through -->
<xsl:template match="text()|@*">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

In your first stylesheet you're implicitly matching all text nodes with `node()`, thus overriding the default action. Then, in the `B2` template, you output your target value and apply no further templates, which stops processing.

In the second stylesheet, you explicitly apply templates to all children of `LOG/MATERIALS/item/SALESPRICES/item`, causing the default templates to process the nodes you don't explicitly handle. Because you explicitly handle `B2` without applying templates to its children, the default templates are never invoked for those nodes. But the default templates *are* applied to the children of `B1`.

Adding the following template to your second stylesheet would override the default action for text nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="text()|@*"></xsl:template>
```

With the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MenuItems><Mi>234567</Mi></MenuItems>
```

More:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are running into the [built in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule).

Specifically the text rule - this will copy text nodes if not overridden.