# A Beginner Question on XSLT "apply-templates"

Tags: xml, xslt

For a very simple XML like this:

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

and a simple xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:apply-templates/>  
</xsl:template>
```

why does it produce output like:

```
Empire Burlesque
Bob Dylan
USA
Columbia
10.90
1985

Hide your heart
Bonnie Tyler
UK
CBS Records
9.90
1988

Greatest Hits
Dolly Parton
USA
RCA
9.90
1982
```

Where have all the XML tags gone? Should I surround `<xsl:apply-templates/>` with 
`<xsl:copy>` tags to get that to work?

Comment: You probably should not " surround with `<xsl:apply-templates/>` with tags " -- anyone can show you what to do -- especially if you show us the wanted output and explain any desired rules/properties/constraints for the transformation.

Comment: First duplicate found [what is the reason behind XSLT parser's this behavior ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360017/what-is-the-reason-behind-xslt-parsers-this-behavior)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of the built-in templates, which *visit* all elements and *print* the values of text and attribute nodes (as long as a template applies to them). See my answer to this previous question for a full explanation:

[XSLT 1.0 text nodes printing by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083511/xslt-1-0-text-nodes-printing-by-default/5083578#5083578)

You can use `xsl:copy` to perform the [identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Which will output a copy of your source document.

Comment: Code provided by OP doesn't "print attribute nodes". Either does empty XSL file. They are printed if they are applied. [Proof link](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule)

Comment: @Flack - Of course you're right, but that's not the built-in template's fault. It's just because OP's XSLT never visits any attribute nodes. I thought about clarifying that. Maybe I will now.