# Why this code doesn't output anything XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am completely new in XSLT. So I am trying to make an example that is supposed to output the value of an element. The output format is plain text format.
This is the XML file called cdcatalog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="catalog.xsl"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>
            <europe_country>Bulgaria</europe_country>
            <azia_coutry>China</azia_coutry>
        </country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

And this is the XSL file called cdcatalog.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="cd">
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output I expect is something like this

```
Empire
Hide your heart
```

But nothing appears in the output window. 
Where am I wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

- You need `<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">` to iterate through the `cd` elements inside the `catalog`. Bear in mind that [the "root" of your document isn't the `<catalog>` element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3134169/300836).
- You say the xsl file is called `cdcatalog.xsl`, but your `href` in the xml is `catalog.xsl`.

Answer (score 1):

When writing templates, try to target (i.e. *match*) directly the content you are interested in (the `title` elements, in this case).

**XSLT Stylesheet**

As you can see, there is a second template that matches `text()`. If we omit it, *all* text content from the input document is output, because that is the *default behaviour* of the XSLT processor for text nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="title">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Text Output**

```
Empire
Hide your heart
```

---

Try this solution online [here](http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38YC).

---

By the way, make sure your elements are *consistently* named. An element called `azia_coutry` is completely different from `asia_coutry` or `asia_country`.