# xslt not working as expected with root element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have xml as follows

```
   <pin>
        <securityProfile>
            <userName>userName</userName>
        </securityProfile>
    </pin>
```

Expected output

```
     <user_id>
          <userName>userName</userName>
    </user_id>
```

xslt

```
<xsl:template match="/pin">
    <user_id>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="securityProfile/userName"/>
    </user_id>      
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="userName">
    ..........................
</xsl:template>
```

If i change `<xsl:template match="/pin">` to `<xsl:template match="/">` , then it is not working.What might be the reason .here pin is the root element.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: [Here is an excellent explanation of how `/` works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127108/xsl-xsltemplate-match) for the _root node_ (usually the document node, but can be absent) and how it differs from `/somename` for selecting the _root element(s)_, usually one, and colloquially considered the root by many, but they aren't the same and the difference is subtle, but important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i change `<xsl:template match="/pin">` to <`xsl:template
>   match="/">` , then it is not working.

If you change that, you also need to change:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="securityProfile/userName"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="pin/securityProfile/userName"/>
```

Otherwise you're applying templates to non-existing nodes.

Comment: Here root element is pin ?Then why i need to give again pin here ?

Comment: You're not giving it *again*. Your template's match pattern establishes the  `/` *root node* as the current context. From this context, the relative path to `userName` is `pin/securityProfile/userName`.

Comment: I thought that <xsl:template match="/"> , <xsl:template match="/pin"> , both are same.Am i right or wrong ?

Comment: You are wrong. `<xsl:template match="/">` matches the **root node**.  `<xsl:template match="/pin">` matches the **root element**. The root element is a child of the root node. -- Note that different standards may use different terms to describe these two nodes; see: http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/root.html

Comment: Thank you .I got it now.