# xPath extract node issue

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have this XML file:

```
<produce>
    <item>apple</item>
    <item>banana</item>
    <item>pepper</item>
    <item>apples</item>
    <item>pizza</item>
</produce>
```

and I want extract only items' name , for example apple,banana,pepper,apples and pizza, for this reason I create this XSL file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
    <ul>
    <li><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></li>
    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I don't understand why it doesn't work.
Maybe I don't understand how works `text()` function.
Can you help me?

Comment: XPath for fetching only text will be `//produce/item/text()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are outputting on `li` for the current node, which is the top-level document node. The `text()` function will get the text node that is the immediate child of the current node. But in your XML the text nodes you want are children of `item` elements.

If you want an `li` for each `item` in your XML, you first need to select those `item` elements, using either `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:apply-templates`.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
    <ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="produce/item">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></li>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: sorry the "/" represent which node ?

Comment: It effectively represents the XML document. It is the parent of the `produce` node in your case.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127108/xsl-xsltemplate-match for a full explanation.

Comment: @ginogino `/*` is neither in your question nor in this answer. `/*` means the outermost element of an XML document - `produce` in your case, but the `*` means the element could have any name. If you have more unrelated questions, please accept this answer and then ask a new question.