# XSLT Trying to extract data from sibling node

Tags: xml, xslt

Hey I am trying to check if there is a email present in my xml document, if yes is the password which is the sibling node the same as passed password i am getting the password and email as parameter. So far what I have tried is

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="customers//email[text()=$emailPassed] and 
      customers//password[text()=$password]">
        true
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The XML file is here

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <customers>
     <customer>
      <customerid>74</customerid>
       <firstname>test</firstname>
        <lastname>test</lastname>
        <email>xx.xx@gmail.com</email>
        <password>591c2fdfc6d2d</password>
      </customer>
    </customers>
```

Can you please help me out with this i am stuck for quite an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might make more sense to use `xsl:if` here, but the expression you are looking for is this

```
    <xsl:if test="customers/customer[email=$emailPassed and password=$password]">
        <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
```

Or better still, just to this

```
<xsl:value-of select="boolean(customers/customer[email=$emailPassed and password=$password])" />
```

This will also return `false` in the case of no match.

Comment: one question here, why would you have to specify the customers element when i am matching / at the start

Comment: Because `/` matches the document node, which is the parent of the root element (`customers` in your case)

Comment: Thanks Tim really appreciate that.

Comment: This question might give more information... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127108/xsl-xsltemplate-match

Comment: could you please guide me how to debug your xslt code and maybe some type of guide to follow while writing xslt code thanks